# How to get all combinations of a list where two elements next to each other can become one element

Tags: python, list, combinations

I'm trying to get all combinations of a list where two elements **next to each other** may "become one". For example;

```py
>>> list = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
>>> get_comb(list)
[['ab', 'c' 'd'], ['a', 'bc' 'd'], ['a', 'b', 'cd'] ['ab', 'cd']]
```

The tricky part is that two elements can become one, and I've been stuck on this problem for a long time. I tried something like this;

```py
list_split_up = [list[i:i+2] for i in range(0, len(list), 2)]
indexes = [str(i) for i in range(len(list_split_up)) if len(list_split_up[i])==2]
comb = [''.join(l) for i in range(len(indexes),0,-1) for l in itertools.combinations(indexes, i)]
```

where I get all the indexes of possible combinations, and with that I can get create what I want - but the problem is that it only gives me combinations like `['ab', 'cd']` (because I split the list into two and two), and I therefore won't get i.e. `['a', 'bc', 'd']`, as I want.

Comment: What have you tried so far, and what results are you getting?

Comment: What do you mean by "can become one"? What is the condition for this?

Comment: @CrazyChucky I made an edit now which shows some of what I've tried.

Comment: @IoaTzimas What I mean by become "one" is that two elements can become one element, and thus the amount of combinations will be far more. For example a list with 3 elements , i.eg. ['a', 'b', 'c'] can become a list with only 2, ['ab', 'c']. Does that clear it up?

Comment: What about ['a', 'bc'] isn't valid in the above example?

Comment: @IoaTzimas It's completely valid, and that's the point :)

Comment: So, you want all combinations where AT LEAST one pair of consecutive items become one? Result will include cases with 2, 3 pairs etc as well?

Comment: @IoaTzimas Yes, exactly!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a simple recursive solution:

```
example = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f']

def generate(tail, head=[]):
    for i in range(1, len(tail)):
        current = tail[:]
        current[i-1:i+1] = [current[i-1] + current[i]]
        yield head + current
        yield from generate(current[i:], head + current[:i])

for item in generate(example):
    print(item)
```

Output:

```
['ab', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f']
['ab', 'cd', 'e', 'f']
['ab', 'cd', 'ef']
['ab', 'c', 'de', 'f']
['ab', 'c', 'd', 'ef']
['a', 'bc', 'd', 'e', 'f']
['a', 'bc', 'de', 'f']
['a', 'bc', 'd', 'ef']
['a', 'b', 'cd', 'e', 'f']
['a', 'b', 'cd', 'ef']
['a', 'b', 'c', 'de', 'f']
['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'ef']
```

Answer (score 1):

This looks like a perfect case for dynamic programming, working from the end.

```
[] -> []
['e'] -> ['e']
['d', 'e'] -> ['de'] prepended to all solutions for []
               plus ['d'] prepended to all solutions for ['e']
['c', 'd', 'e'] -> ['cd'] prepended to all solutions for ['e']
                plus ['c'] prepended to all solutions for ['de']
and so on.
```

Comment: Solid approach, but wouldn't the solution for `['e']` be the empty list? There are no doubles to be made.

Comment: I think the code is simpler if you include the degenerate case.  At the end, you can optionally delete the one degenerate element from your list if that's what you want.

Comment: Hah!  I just realized that if you include the degenerate case (all singletons), then there are Fib(n) answers when you have a string of length n!   This follows directly from the recursive formula I used.

Answer (score 1):

Let `n` be the length of your original list. We will assume the maximum number of elements that can be combined at a time is `max_len`. So if `max_len=2` then `"abc"` is invalid, but `"ab"` is since the latter combines 2 adjacent elements while the former combines 3 adjacent elements.

Now you can encode each solution as a tuple of number of elements to be combined. So `["ab","c","d"]` will be encoded as `[2,1,1]`; similarly `["abcd"]` will be `[4]`, `["a","bcd"]` will be `[1,3]` etc. Now we have reduced the problem to generating these encodings.

Formally these encodings have the property:

1. have elements from the set `[1, ..., max_len]`
2. sum of elements is `n`

There are many ways of generating this; here is one. We are generating all combinations and filtering those which match criterion 1 and 2. Then getting the solution from the encoding.

```py
from itertools import combinations_with_replacement, accumulate, takewhile

# generating the data
n = 4
ls = list(chr(ord('a')+e) for e in range(n))
print("data = ", ls)

# setting the maximum number of adjacent elements that can be combined at a time
max_len = 2
max_len = min(n,max_len)
print("max_len = ", max_len)

# actual implementation
combinations = combinations_with_replacement(range(1,max_len+1),n)
combinations_with_cumsum = (zip(e,accumulate(e)) for e in combinations)
combinations_till_maxElm = (list(takewhile(lambda x: x[1]<=n,e)) for e in combinations_with_cumsum)
combinations_till_maxElm = filter(lambda x:x[-1][1]==n, combinations_till_maxElm)

indices = (
    [0] + [e[1] for e in elm]
    for elm in set(map(tuple,combinations_till_maxElm))
)

indices_si_ei = (zip(e,e[1:]) for e in indices)

print("result = ", [["".join(ls[si:ei]) for si,ei in e] for e in indices_si_ei])
```

Play along = https://repl.it/@bigyanbhar/SO65365566#main.py

There is definitely a better way than generating all combinations. The easiest is to write your own `combinations_with_replacement` such that it generates valid ones only thereby cutting down extra branches. Happy coding!

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution (l is the original list):

```
import itertools

k=len(l)-1

m=[]

for i in range(1, len(l)//2+1):
    comb=[x for x in itertools.permutations([1]*i+[0]*(k-i))]
    m=list(set(m))
    m.extend(comb)

def isvalid(x):
    for i in range(len(x)-1):
        if x[i]==x[i+1]==1:
            return False
    return True

m=[i for i in m if isvalid(i)]

res=[]

for i in m:
    temp=[]
    for x in range(len(i)):
        if i[x]==0 and (x==0 or i[x-1]==0):
            temp.append(l[x])
        if i[x]==1:
            temp.append(l[x]+l[x+1])
    if i[-1]==0:
        temp.append(l[-1])
    res.append(temp)

res=[tuple(i) for i in res]
res=list(set(res))
print(res)
```

Examples:

1.

```
l=  ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
```

Output:

```
[('ab', 'c', 'd'), ('a', 'b', 'cd'), ('a', 'bc', 'd'), ('ab', 'cd')]
```

2. 

```
l=['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']
```

Output:

```
[('ab', 'c', 'de'), ('a', 'b', 'cd', 'e'), ('a', 'bc', 'de'), ('a', 'b', 'c', 'de'), ('a', 'bc', 'd', 'e'), ('ab', 'c', 'd', 'e'), ('ab', 'cd', 'e')]
```

Comment: Although your solution works, `comb=[x for x in itertools.permutations([1]*i+[0]*(k-i))]` causes a MemoryError very easily once the list gets larger than 12 ish. Do you believe there's some other way of doing it? Thansk btw!

Answer (score 0):

You can use recursion with a generator:

```
l = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
def get_groups(d):
  yield tuple(d)
  if (k:=len(d)) > 1:
    for i in range(len(d)-1):
      yield from get_groups([*d[:i], d[i]+d[i+1], *([] if i+2 >= k else d[i+2:])])

print(list(map(list, set(get_groups(l)))))
```

Output:

```
[['a', 'b', 'cd'], ['abc', 'd'], ['a', 'bc', 'd'], ['ab', 'c', 'd'], ['abcd'], ['a', 'bcd'], ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'], ['ab', 'cd']]
```

Comment: Your solution includes 3 elements combined ('abc'). It must be 2 elements max